# Свой View или текст в строке состояния

Tags: android

Помогите понять как в строку состояния выводить свой текст или View.
Как например вот тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите куда смотреть? Ничего не нашел в классе Notification.

Comment: Это обычная иконка уведомлений, `Bitmap` которой рисуется в рантайме.

Comment: @eugeneek, тем не мение, стоит задача, выводить значение в статус бар версии API 17 | android 4.2.2. как в этой версии запихнуть Bitmap в  setSmallIcon?

Answer (score 1):

В api 23 появился метод, который позволяет установить в уведомление в качестве small icon
объект `Icon`, который можно получить из нарисованного в рантайме `Bitmap`:

```
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(bitmap));
```

Для api < 23 в качестве иконки можно устанавливать только `Drawable`, которые находятся в ресурсах приложения. А ресурсы в рантайме создавать нельзя. Возможно когда нибудь методы бекпортируют и добавят в support library.

Если набор выводимых значений ограничен, то для api < 23 можно использовать [`LevelListDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html). То есть, для каждого значения нужно нарисовать иконку, положить в ресурсы, создать их список и устанавливать, указывая `level`. Например:

**ic_wifi_signal.xml**

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_1" />
    <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_2" />
    <item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_3" />
    <item android:maxLevel="3" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_4" />
</level-list>
```

Установка иконки (с ресурсом `ic_wifi_signal_3`):

```
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_wifi_signal, 2);
```